# MapFragment - NullPointerException - Google Maps V2 - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm getting an NullPointerException with the following code:

```
private ProjectionProxy proxy = new ProjectionProxy();
private GoogleMap mMap = null;
private Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle load) { 
    super.onCreate(load);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_ride_tracking);

    //mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView)).getMap();

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    int result = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView);
    //mMap = mapFragment.getMap();

    Log.e("RideTracking", "Google Map VALUE:"+mMap);

    if (mMap != null) { 
        proxy.setProjection(mMap.getProjection());
    }
```

The line where the NullPointerException is happening is this line of code:

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I'm not initializing my mMap variable to null.  What is my issue here?

Comment: Are you using Support library?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Support library

Comment: Not sure but Try this `mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();`

Comment: Are you sure there's a valid fragment in your layout? Seems like the fragment that's retrieved by "findFragment" is null. But without the layout file and without a stack trace, there's not much I can say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to check the MapFragment that you've created in the XML of the Activity. Check mine; it's working.

```
...

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

...
```

Is yours different? Also, you checked if you put the correct permissions and metadata on the AndroidManifest.xml?

Here's the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

And here's the metadata section:

```
<application>

    ...

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="HERE GOES YOUR API KEY" />

</application>
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 7):

MainActivity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer. If you know what is wrong with OP's code, please elaborate.

Comment: GigoNet Gigolashvili answer is correct.
Importent difference is:If you are using API level < 12, use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment in code and xml.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing this from manifest.xml
`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"                              android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>`