# java.lang.NullPointerException is happened in my onViewCreated(fragment.java)

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I am trying to navigation view and use one fragment to show google map. other fragments work well to show some text view but when I try to load google map this happens.

Logcat:

```
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708): Process: com.cubecode.mapdhaka, PID: 13708
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at com.cubecode.mapdhaka.FindPeopleFragment.onViewCreated(FindPeopleFragment.java:43)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:698)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
05-14 20:36:50.197: E/AndroidRuntime(13708):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    // shopping zones
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new ShoppingZoneFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

this is the fragment

```
 public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {
private GoogleMap googleMap;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
    initilizeMap();
    return rootView;
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) private void initilizeMap()
{
    MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
     if (fragment != null)
     {
      googleMap = fragment.getMap();

     }
}
```

}

Comment: are you sure that you have declared a `MapFragment` into `fragment_find_people.xml` con id map?

Comment: Apparently, there is no fragment with the ID  `R.id.map`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MapFragment - NullPointerException - Google Maps V2 - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591750/mapfragment-nullpointerexception-google-maps-v2-android)

Comment: @Blackbelt I have declared MapFragment in the xml file

Comment: changed the fragment a bit and now I don't get the null pointer but having another problem. when I move from FindPeopleFragment to another and try to return to this again, the app crashes

Comment: The app crashes with a new error? If so, please post a new question for new problems